# MS Access: form filter with Check Box to apply predefined criteria

Tags: forms, ms-access, filter

I'm new to MS Access.
I'm trying to build a form which i can filter by clicking a checkbox to apply predefined criteria.
In my particular case, tblIssues contains ClosedOnDate field.

I want my form to be able to show records for which ClosedOnDate is Null (say, when form CheckBox state is False) and all records when form CheckBox is state is True.

The mechanics of applying a filter in a form are fairly clear to me , but i don't know how to tie a non CheckBox field in a table with a checkbox on a form.

I've tried to search forums for tips, but cant locate any meaningful posts on the topic.

Many thanks for any help.

Pawel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a dynamic parameterized query as form RecordSource, consider:

```
WHERE IIf(ClosedOnDate IS NULL, 0, 1) LIKE IIf(Forms!formname!checkboxname = 0, 0, "*");
```

Alternatively, write a VBA procedure that conditionally builds filter criteria and applies to form filter property.

```
Dim strWhere As String
...
If Me.checkboxname = False Then strWhere = "ClosedOnDate IS NULL"
...
Me.Filter = strWhere
Me.FilterOn = True
```

For more extensive example of code building filter criteria, review http://allenbrowne.com/ser-62code.html

Be sure to set checkbox TripleState property to No.

Comment: Thanks June7, In the second scenario, where do I apply the VBA code? Is it "On Click" event of the CheckBox or "On Filter" event of the Form?

Comment: Depends. Do you want to build criteria with input from multiple controls? If not then could just use click event, otherwise, a button. I don't see how OnFilter event would be useful to set a filter. Did you review the linked article?